# Aurelia - repeat.for json

Tags: javascript, json, aurelia

I am new to Aurelia.

I'm trying to iterate (repeat.for) through some json that looks like below.  I am able to do so with a manual concat but the number of artists is variable.  Below for example works.

```
         return this.http.fetch(baseUrl + "/artists/" + token + "&search=" + searchCreator)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            //for (var i = 0; i < response.resultsCount; i++){              
            //    response += response.artists[i].objects;               
            //}
            return response.artists[0].objects.concat(response.artists[1].objects);
        });
```

How can I return all objects for all artists?  I've tried doing this with a for loop but I can't get it to work.  Should I return response.artists and then work with that in my view model?  This is what the view looks like:

```
    <tr repeat.for="item of items">
      <td>${item.title}</td>
      <td>${item.displayName}</td>
      <td>${item.objectNumber}</td>       
    </tr>
```

json example:

```
{

"source": "My Museum",
"language": "EN",
"resultsCount": ​58,
"artists": 

[{

"artistID": ​47171,
"alphaSort": "Smith Eloise Vega",
"displayName": "Eloise Vega Smith",
"beginDate": "0",
"endDate": "0",
"displayDate": "",
"sex": "Female",
"nationality": "",
"objectCount": ​1,
"objects": 

[{
        "objectNumber": "209.2015",
        "objectID": ​188963,
        "title": "Album cover for Urszula Dudziak, Newborn Light",
        "displayName": "Eloise Vega Smith",
        "alphaSort": "Smith Eloise Vega",
        "artistID": ​47171,
        "displayDate": "",
        "dated": "1974",
        "dateBegin": ​1974,
        "dateEnd": ​1974,
        "medium": "Lithograph",
        "dimensions": "12 1/2 x 12 1/4\" (31.8 x 31.1 cm)",
        "department": "Architecture & Design",
        "classification": "A&D Graphic Design",
        "onView": ​0,
        "provenance": "",
        "description": "",
        "objectStatusID": ​1,
        "creditLine": "Committee on Architecture and Design Funds",
        "imageID": "502407",
        "thumbnail": "http:///TMSImages/Size1/Images/TR15211_10_RICR.jpg",
        "fullImage": "http:///TMSImages/Size3/Images/TR15211_10_RICR.jpg",
        "lastModifiedDate": "2015-09-17T01:00:08"
    }
]

},
{

"artistID": ​5479,
"alphaSort": "Smith Charles",
"displayName": "Charles Smith",
"beginDate": "1893",
"endDate": "1987",
"displayDate": "American, 1893–1987",
"sex": "Male",
"nationality": "American",
"objectCount": ​6,
"objects": 

[{

"objectNumber": "369.1941",
"objectID": ​67911,
"title": "Red Circle",
"displayName": "Charles Smith",
"alphaSort": "Smith Charles",
"artistID": ​5479,
"displayDate": "American, 1893–1987",
"dated": "1940",
"dateBegin": ​1940,
"dateEnd": ​1940,
"medium": "Monoprint",
"dimensions": "Sheet 21 1/8 x 14 3/4\" (53.8 x 37.5 cm) Comp.  20 x 14 3/4\" (50.8 x 37.5 cm)",
"department": "Prints & Illustrated Books",
"classification": "Print",
"onView": ​0,
"provenance": "",
"description": "Color monoprint, printed from movable forms",
"objectStatusID": ​1,
"creditLine": "Purchase",
"imageID": "260293",
"thumbnail": "http:///TMSImages/Size1/Images/369_1941_RICR.jpg",
"fullImage": "http:///TMSImages/Size3/Images/369_1941_RICR.jpg",
"lastModifiedDate": "2015-03-31T01:06:18"

},
{

"objectNumber": "214.1942",
"objectID": ​64517,
"title": "Abstraction",
"displayName": "Charles Smith",
"alphaSort": "Smith Charles",
"artistID": ​5479,
"displayDate": "American, 1893–1987",
"dated": "c. 1942",
"dateBegin": ​1942,
"dateEnd": ​1942,
"medium": "Woodcut",
"dimensions": "composition (irreg.): 11 1/4 x 3 3/4\" (28.5 x 9.6 cm); sheet: 14 9/16 x 7 1/16\" (37 x 17.9 cm)",
"department": "Prints & Illustrated Books",
"classification": "Print",
"onView": ​0,
"provenance": "",
"description": "Woodcut, printed in black, dark green yellow, deep blue and strong red brown",
"objectStatusID": ​1,
"creditLine": "Given anonymously",
"imageID": "195213",
"thumbnail": "http:///TMSImages/Size1/Images/214_1942_RICR.jpg",
"fullImage": "http:///TMSImages/Size3/Images/214_1942_RICR.jpg",
"lastModifiedDate": "2014-09-19T01:05:22"

},
etc.....
```

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with LINQ, you could use a library like `jslinq` and do the following:

```
return jslinq(response.artists)
    .selectMany(function(artist){
        return artist.objects
    }).toList();
```

of course I would only include jslinq if I planned to use it more than once in the project. If you don't want the overhead, your solution with concat should work just fine:

```
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < response.artists.length; i++) {
    result = result.concat(response.artists[i].objects);
}
return result;
```

Comment: Ugh!  I tried the array approach 50 times without success and then now it just worked.  It is response.artists[i].objects BTW.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The built-in [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method would also work:  `let result = response.artists.reduce((value, artist) => value.concat(artist.objects), []));`